# APC fetch returns null, codeigniter progress bar

Tags: php, codeigniter, apc

I have an imagehost style website running codeigniter and I'm trying to implement a progress bar using APC to display while the file uploads.

Right now when I either visit the progress view page, or via ajax, it's just returning `bool(false)`.

I've tested `apc_store` and fetch within that view just to see if APC is functioning at all, and that way works, it seems my upload form way doesn't work with APC though.

My progress view (domain.com/progress/KEY) http://pastebin.com/m2qF1BEw

My `progress()` in controller:

```
function progress() {
    $this->load->model('Site_model');

    $data['PROGRESS_KEY']= $this->input->post('progress_key');
    $this->load->view('progress', $data);
}
```

The key being set on my upload page view:

```
$up_id = md5(uniqid(rand()));
```

My form within my upload page view:

```
<form action="http://domain.com/site" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" value="a1105b41e90ed6cdaa7bdef008da40ee" id="progress_key"  />

    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" value="" multiple="multiple" id="file" accept="image/*,application/pdf"  />

    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" />

</form>

<iframe id="upload_frame" class="nodisplay" name="upload_frame" frameborder="0" border="0" src="" scrolling="no" scrollbar="no" > </iframe>
```

Here's the JS on the form page that requests the progress view each second:

http://pastebin.com/6QW3sZLz

**Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?** thanks

Also here's all my apc php.ini settings confirmed by phpinfo()

```
apc.cache_by_default    On      On
apc.canonicalize        On      On
apc.coredump_unmap      Off     Off
apc.enable_cli  On      On
apc.enabled     On      On
apc.file_md5    Off     Off
apc.file_update_protection      2       2
apc.filters     no value        no value
apc.gc_ttl      3600    3600
apc.include_once_override       Off     Off
apc.lazy_classes        Off     Off
apc.lazy_functions      Off     Off
apc.max_file_size       30M     30M
apc.mmap_file_mask      no value        no value
apc.num_files_hint      1000    1000
apc.preload_path        no value        no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off     Off
apc.rfc1867     On      On
apc.rfc1867_freq        10k     10k
apc.rfc1867_name        APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS     APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix      upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  default default
apc.shm_segments        1       1
apc.shm_size    32M     32M
apc.slam_defense        On      On
apc.stat        On      On
apc.stat_ctime  Off     Off
apc.ttl 7200    7200
apc.use_request_time    On      On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096    4096
apc.user_ttl    7200    7200
apc.write_lock  On      On
```

Answer (score 0):

well this looks wrong to me

```
function progress() {
    $this->load->model('Site_model');

    $data['PROGRESS_KEY']= $this->input->post('progress_key'); // error here
/* above you fetch "progress key" should change to APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS */

    $this->load->view('progress', $data);
}
```

and in this input field the name is APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS, and **you are fetching the ID**

```
<input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" value="a1105b41e90ed6cdaa7bdef008da40ee" id="progress_key"  />
```

also you javascript looks ok but you are not getting the current value , you are setting it by hand.

```
$("#progress_key").val();
```

should give you the value of the input field.

Comment: I just made that edit and /progress/*KEY*

returns bool(false) still :/

edit: just trying your js change now...

Comment: you can ignore that i've hard coded the key in the JS pastebin, its actually set to the progress_key value in the PHP, just hardcoded to show in the example.

 I've even tried hardcoding in a key on the upload page to test, same result.